# How can I save/restore AdaptiveMetropolis step method state?

Tags: python, numpy, pymc

I've been running some fairly expensive models with a long burn-in time.  I'd like to save & restore the state of the AdaptiveMetropolis step methods (at least) to reduce the burn-in time.  Is there a recommended way to do this, or should I just pickle the `step_method.current_state()` dict and try to update `step_method.C`, `step_method.proposal_sd`, and maybe others from pickled data when I want to restart?

(cross-post from deprecated Google Group forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymc/6U72WuuXmMo)

Comment: At the moment this seems to be a computing question ('how do I get this software to do this particular thing?') rather than a statistics question. Could you more clearly identify a specific statistical issue, or consider flagging this to be moved to StackOverflow?

Comment: can you show us some code? also please tag your question. this looks like python (based on the pickle reference)

Comment: @booyaa - sorry, this is a pymc question that was intended for their forums, which told me to post on cross-validated, which then redirected me here.... I'll work up a code sample...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `save_state` and `restore_sampler_state` methods? They should work with any non-sqlite backend (e.g. pickle, txt). The former should save the sampler information to the database; here is an example:

```
    {'stochastics': {'alpha': array([-0.20073951]), 'beta': array([ 2.77634734])}, 'step_methods': {'AdaptiveMetropolis_beta_alpha': {'C': array([[ 41.28628017,   2.79567393],
       [  2.79567393,   1.8832875 ]]), '_trace': [array([ 10.4010084 ,   1.48321645]), ... [ 0.43509455,  1.30152996]]), 
       'accepted': 69.0, 'shrink_if_necessary': False}}, 
       'sampler': {'status': 'ready', '_iter': 2000, '_tune_interval': 1000, '_tuned_count': 0, '_tune_throughout': True, '_burn_till_tuned': False, '_current_iter': 2000, '_burn': 0, '_thin': 1}}
```

Comment: What if the sampling was run with a RAM backend?  Is there any way to save that state?

Comment: The state will be stored in a `_state_` attribute in the ram backend as a dict.

Comment: There is no `_state_` attribute, and `_state` is just a list.  `.current_state()` reads the attributes referred to by `_state`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Just found this old question, probably `MCMC.get_state()['step_methods'].keys()` shows what the OP is looking for.